# Error while resizing image using imagemagick in nodejs , How to Fix this?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick library for resizing image to fit for the UI specification,

I have installed imagemagick by following cmd:
 sudo npm install imagemagick

Installation is done correctly, but i am getting the error while resizing,

My code :

```
                var im = require('imagemagick');
                im.resize({
                            srcPath:"/tmp/"+imageName,
                            dstPath:"/home/image/" + imageName,
                            width:43,
                            height :43,
                       }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                       if (err) {
                                console.log('error while resizing image ' + err);
                                }
                          });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
      Error: Command failed: execvp(): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dstPath:"/home/image/" + imageName,
```

**Edit**: Have you installed imagemagick library? If not then you have to install it. If you are in ubuntu do `apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: Sorry i missed quotes while editing my code...This is not an actual issue. its typing mistake

Comment: i am in unbuntu , i have installed using sudo npm install imagemagick inside my project folder, It reflect in my project also...